# Angular template text in Safari on backwards navigation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, safari, back

I'm working on an Angular app that makes a call to a data service and then repeats the results in the view.  Each result has a unique, external link.  I've found that, in Safari, when you click the link and then navigate backwards with the browser button, you see only the bracketed Angular template text.  So,

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <div>{{i.name}}</div>
  <div>{{i.location}}</div>
  <div><a href="{{i.link}}">{{i.link_name}}</a></div>
</div>
```

yields

```
{{i.name}}
{{i.location}}
{{i.link_name}}
```

with the anchor being just an empty link.  This phenomenon does not appear in Chrome.  The app is being served by Rails.

Answer (score 0):

That is basically uncompiled html by angular shown on HTML. In that case I'd prefer you to use `ng-bind` directive to html on page.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
  <div ng-bind="i.name"></div>
  <div ng-bind="i.location">{{i.}}</div>
  <div><a ng-href="{{i.link}}" ng-bind="i.link_name"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This prevents the handlebars from showing up, which is a plus, but the app still doesn't compile.  I may have left this unclear- the ng-repeat doesn't iterate.  There's just one 'article' of the raw Angular template.

Comment: May i know what you don't understand?

Comment: The text appears raw, as if the app hasn't run at all.  Your solution is an improvement, since nothing appears if the app fails but it would be better if it would look the same as it did before the user clicked the link and navigated back.